# Visual Studio 2013 Sitecore intellisense broken after run code analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sitecore, intellisense, code-analysis, sitecore6

I'm using VS 2013 and Sitecore 6.5.

I've configure the sitecore intellisense for my aspx code, and it works.

then... when I run the code analysis, the intellisense die.

Anyone know how to retain the sitecore intellisense after run code analysis?

Comment: Where are you losing intellisense at?  In aspx/ascx files or in .cs files?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your solution, delete the .suo file and reopen the solution.